# Read all files in directory and output the files that contain certain regexes in them

Tags: python, regex, glob, pypdf, os.path

I am trying to read all files in my directory and output the ones that contain the regexes and also what the regex in each file was.

```
 import glob
import re
import PyPDF2
#-------------------------------------------------Input----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
folder_path = "/home/"
file_pattern = "/*"
folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

#Search for Emails
regex1= re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')
#Search for Phone Numbers
regex2 = re.compile(r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d')

match_list=[]

for file in folder_contents:

    if re.search(r".*(?=pdf$)",file):
        #this is pdf
        with open(file, 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)  
            content = pageObj.extractText()
            read_file = open(file,'rb')
            #print("{}".format(file))

    elif re.search(r".*(?=csv$)",file):
        #this is csv
        with open(file,"r+",encoding="utf-8") as csv:
            read_file = csv.read()
            #print("{}".format(file))
    elif re.search(r"/jupyter",file):
        print("wow")
    elif re.search(r"/scikit",file):
        print("wow")
    else:
        read_file = open(file, 'rb').read()
       #print("{}".format(file))
        continue
    if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file):
                print(read_file)
```

I managed to write the below code but it is giving the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-f614d35e0441> in <module>()
     38        #print("{}".format(file))
     39         continue
---> 40     if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file):
     41                 print(read_file)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

is there any way to get this to work without the error?

Comment: `the ones that contain the regexes` Your term is not valid. The files don't really contain regex. You are using regex to match text in the file.

Comment: wHAT DO you mean by that? I am trying to filter my directory for two regex strings

Comment: Whata ? you say you're trying to find a regex in a string ? It's symantics, regex work on a _target_ strring, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm trying to match a regex pattern in a file

Answer (score 0):

Replace your read file code with this:

```
with open(File, mode='rb') as file:
    readFile = file.read()
```

Comment: I did you suggstion but still get the following error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a3bca150e30a> in <module>()
     39        #print("{}".format(file))
     40         continue
---> 41     if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file):
     42         email=regex1.findall(read_file)
     43         print(email)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I am hoping you have changed variable name from read_file to readFile ?

Comment: Also, just for testing purposes, requesting you to comment all the code and just keep 1 block of `if` statement and see..as rest is all same!!

Comment: Yes I did. I have made that change. Still giving same error.

Comment: In the `pdf` loop your `content` contains all the text why are you opening 1 more file...just pass that content to your regex and it should work

Comment: I changed that and it is giving me the following error: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Append a `b` to your search pattern like so: `b'<title>(.*?)</title>'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. On my regexes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184643/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-james-davinport).

Answer (score 0):

With `read()` only `open(filename)` will work. Just replace with this and you will get your problem solved.

```
read_file = open(file).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

First i apologize to other people who answered this question, because i will said something about OP former question.

About OP, you should not copy code without thinking.

`Content` is the page you already read. It means your code should be `read_file = content`. And why i write `read_file = #`, because i think you will add extra code. But it should not read same file again.

```
with open(file, 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)  
        content = pageObj.extractText()
        read_file = open(file,'rb') 
        #^---^---^ according to your former question, `read_file` should  be `content`
```

And there will be other problems occur. you should add `continue` after `print("wow")`.

```
elif re.search(r"/jupyter",file):
    print("wow")
elif re.search(r"/scikit",file):
    print("wow")
```

otherwise your code will keep runing, then error occur. because you did not read anything.

```
if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file):
    print(read_file)
```

Comment: You are correct..that is what I told OP, if you read the comments to my answer below!!

Comment: Can you chat? Ur answer doesnt make sense.